# I have apache2 installed twice, need to uninstall one

Tags: macos, apache2

During my newbie phases I was not aware that Max OSX had appache2 installed by default.
I manually installed it and now I have two versions running and it's extremely confusing, because at times I don't know to which version my developments point to. As of now, I have two version in the following locations:

1. /etc/apache2/ (I believe is the default installation)
2. /opt/local/apache2 (I believe this is the one I manually installed)

How do I uninstall version 2 (the one I manually installed)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Being that it's in `/opt`, the directory [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) uses, have you tried `port uninstall apache2`?

Comment: Yes, I forgot until after the question I had installed it through ports. Thanks!